# Promise of the hidden subgroup problem for $\mathbb{Z} mod 2$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups, quantum-mechanics, periodic-functions, quantum-computation

I am going through the talk, [Graph isomorphism, the hidden subgroup problem and identifying quantum states](https://www.lri.fr/qip06/slides/sen.pdf), by Pranab Sen. On slide 3, the promise of the problem is defined as follows. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818248/hidden-subgroup-problem-for-mathbbz-mod-2) is the previous related question I have asked.

> **Promise**: Subgroup $H \le G$ such that $f$ is constant on the left
>   cosets of $H$ and distinct on different cosets.

I am trying to follow the definition with an example. Let's take the example of set G where,

$$
G = \left\{x | x \in \left\{0, 1\right\}^*, |x| \le 3 \right\}\\
= \left\{000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111\right\}
$$

We assume, here the group operation is bit-wise XOR, $\oplus$, which is, in this context, convolution. So, for the group, $G$, if there is a subgroup $H$ with elements $h_i$ and an element $x$ of $G$ not in $H$, the left coset is $\left\{x \oplus h_i | i = 1, 2, \ldots \right\}$.

Suppose the period is $010$. With that, let's define $f$ as follows.

$$
f\left(000\right) \mapsto 111\\
f\left(001\right) \mapsto 101\\
f\left(010\right) = f\left(000 \oplus 010\right) \mapsto 111\\
f\left(011\right) = f\left(001 \oplus 010\right)\mapsto 101\\
f\left(100\right) \mapsto 010\\
f\left(101\right) \mapsto 001\\
f\left(110\right) = f\left(100 \oplus 010\right) \mapsto 010\\
f\left(111\right) = f\left(101 \oplus 010\right) \mapsto 001
$$

So, obviously, $H = \left\{ 010\right\}$.

Now we go by all items in the promise.

**Promise 1 : $H \le G$**

$H \le G$ is true in the sense that $|G| > |H|$.

**Promise 2 : $f$ is content on the left cosets of $H$**

We need to determine the set of left cosets of $H$ first. To determine the left coset we need to know the elements of $G$ which are not in $H$. There are $7$ such elements, $\left\{000, 001, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111 \right\}$. $|H| = 1$  So, always, $i = 1$.

For, $000 \in G, \notin H $ the left coset is $\left\{000 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{010 \right\}$

Because, $|H| = 1$, verification of *Promise 2* is trivial. As there is only one element in the hidden group, $f$ over it is always constant.

**Promise 3**: $f$ is distinct on different cosets

We will have $7$ different cosets. Let $j = 1 \ldots 7$ and be the index of the elements in the set G. So, $x_j \in G$. Let $C_j$ be the coset for $x_j$.

$ \therefore C_1 = \left\{000 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{010 \right\} $

$C_2 = \left\{001 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{011 \right\}$

$C_3 = \left\{011 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{001 \right\}$

$C_4 = \left\{100 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{110 \right\}$

$C_5 = \left\{101 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{111 \right\}$

$C_6 = \left\{110 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{100 \right\}$

$C_7 = \left\{111 \oplus 010 \right\} = \left\{101 \right\}$

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten a bit of group theory.

Subgroups are closed under inverses and the group operation. In particular, they contain the identity element. The identity of your eight-element group $G$ is $000$, and $H=\{000,010\}$, so the cardinality of it is $|H|=2$. Furthermore the number of cosets is $[G:H]=|G|/|H|=8/2=4$, and a subgroup is always *itself* a coset of itself ($H=eH$ where $e\in G$ is the identity). A system of representatives for these cosets (called a transversal) can be read off of the arguments for which you were able to decide the value of the function arbitrarily. This is easy to read off of the table:

1. $000\oplus H=\{000,010\}$
2. $001\oplus H=\{001,011\}$
3. $100\oplus H=\{100,110\}$
4. $101\oplus H=\{101,111\}$

These are the four cosets. They partition $G$. It is easy to check that $f$ is constant on each coset:

1. $f(000)=111=f(010) \quad \checkmark$
2. $f(001)=101=f(011) \quad \checkmark$
3. $f(100)=010=f(110) \quad \checkmark$
4. $f(101)=001=f(111) \quad \checkmark$

Finally, note that the four values taken ($111,101,010,001$) are all distinct.

Comment: this was helpful.